# Apache Derby - case (in)sensitivity

Tags: derby, case-insensitive

i googled around a bit about case insensitive search in apache derby. all google results are very old (2007 the latest). i found that is impossible to search case insensitive without loosing the index ("LOWER" don't uses the index).

Is this still true? Or is there a way to get case insensitive search on indexed varchar/text columns?

thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [collation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/ref/rrefattribcollation.html):

You could use TERRITORY_BASED:SECONDARY` when creating the connector, this was the only way I was able to achieve this:

> `TERRITORY_BASED:SECONDARY`: Territory based with collation strength `SECONDARY`.
>   `SECONDARY` typically means that differences in base letters or accents are
>   considered significant, **whereas differences in case are not considered
>   significant.**

Example:

```
jdbc:derby:MexicanDB;create=true;collation=TERRITORY_BASED:SECONDARY
```

Apparently it is not possible in Derby to create an index over a function:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-455

Another possibility is to store the same value in a lower case column and search in that.

Comment: thx i also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084000/case-insensitive-search-in-java-db-derby

Comment: great, an answer there mentions: http://blogs.oracle.com/kah/entry/derby_10_5_preview_generated to use generated columns, which would be useful for my last proposal

Comment: but your suggestion is less invasive - at the moment the better choice for me.